# Mediation model with covariates and between and within-person mediators

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, mediation, lavaan

I am pretty new to mediation in multilevel models.
I want to run a 2-1-1 (and maybe a 2-2-1) mediation model in R.
The dataset consists of 110 participants with three assessments per day.
covariates = sex ; age ; financial status and beep.  sex ; age ; financial status are all level 2), beep is level 1.
Mediators =  stress level (measured at each assessment), which is disentangling cstress (within-person stress level); bstress (between-person stress level).
Predictor = depression symptoms (measured at baseline = level 2)
Outcome = burnout (measured at each assessment = level 1)

Based on my understanding, using the lavaan package seems to be the most appropriate approach.
However, I am unsure about how to incorporate the covariates in the mediation model. Additionally, I would like to know how to include both between-person stress (level 2 - 2-2-1 mediation) and within-person stress (level 1 - 2-1-1 mediation) as mediators. If it is not recommended, I would like the stress level (stress) without disentangling as a mediator (2-1-1 mediation).
Any assistance with the R code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like the stress level (stress) without disentangling as a mediator (2-1-1 mediation)

Stress is the mediator, so it is an endogenous variable.  The way this is modeled in MLSEM is that you analyze the original variable (**not** decomposed into between/within components) by specifying that variable in both the within- and between-level model syntax.  Notice that this is how the indicators (which are endogenous) are handled in the `?Demo.twolevel` example and on the [lavaan web tutorial](https://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/multilevel.html).

All endogenous Level-1 variables are decomposed in a "latent" way, so you do not need to calculate means or do centering like you would in a multilevel regression (MLM, e.g., with the `lme4` package), which would be the "manifest" way.

- Lüdtke, O., Marsh, H. W., Robitzsch, A., Trautwein, U., Asparouhov, T., & Muthén, B. (2008). The multilevel latent covariate model: A new, more reliable approach to group-level effects in contextual studies. *Psychological Methods, 13*(3), 203–229. https://doi.org/10.1037/a0012869

As you will see in [the examples](https://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/multilevel.html), the exogenous Level-1 variables *can* be specified in the Level-1 model only, in which case they will not be decomposed.  Any Level-2 (only) variables, such as your covariates, appear only in the Level-2 syntax.  Thus, your indirect effects exist only at Level 2.

- Preacher, K. J., Zyphur, M. J., & Zhang, Z. (2010). A general multilevel SEM framework for assessing multilevel mediation. *Psychological Methods, 15*(3), 209–233. https://doi.org/10.1037/a0020141
- Preacher, K. J., Zhang, Z., & Zyphur, M. J. (2011). Alternative methods for assessing mediation in multilevel data: The advantages of multilevel SEM. *Structural Equation Modeling, 18*(2), 161-182. https://doi.org/10.1080/10705511.2011.557329